# How do I enter recovery mode on LG G2?

Tags: cyanogenmod, lg-g2, twrp

"With the device powered down, hold Volume Down & Power. When the LG logo appears release the buttons and then press them again. Then, press the Power button three times!" (from cyanogenmod wiki) doesn't work for me. I can't seem to figure out how to get to TWRP to restore my phone (currently in a boot loop).

Doesn't connect to adb either because the boot loop stops at LG logo and reboots.

Answer (score 4):

### How to Enter Recovery Mode on LG G2 *(quick easy steps)*

1. Press the **Volume Down** and the **Power Button** at the same time, about **2-3 seconds until the LG Logo shows**.
2. When the LG Logo shows, **release** the buttons **and then press and hold them again**.
3. Keep pressing the buttons until the Recovery Mode Menu displays.

Answer (score 1):

Try This :

- Turn off the device
- Press and hold Volume Down key + Power Key about 6-7 seconds
- Release Power key when LG logo appear
- When still pressing Volume Down key, press Power key one more
- Release Volume down key when Factory Data Reset menu appears

I think this should work, as this is the only way, it opens recovery mode.

Helpful Links :

http://www.recovery-mode.com/android/lg-g2-ls980.html

Comment: THIS HELPED ME !!! and im on V30 Thank You !!!

Answer (score 1):

**Enter Recovery Mode Using `adb`.**

If you are experiencing inconveniences rebooting in recovering mode using the Volume Down and Power buttons, then this method could help to ease the reboot process. It requires `adb`.

`adb reboot recovery`

I used it many times to restart the device in TeamWin Recovery Project, and worked like a charm.

Comment: On LG G2 ls980 I had to run `adb shell` and then run the command `reboot recovery` or it would just do a regular reboot for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

From [Android Geeks](http://www.android.gs/how-to-enter-recovery-mode-on-lg-g2/):

> 1. First of all, take your phone and press the power button; the select “power off”.
> 2. Wait while your phone is shutting down; wait a few seconds and then proceed.
> 3. Now, press the volume down and power button at the same time for 2 or 3 seconds until the LG logo appears on the display.
> 4. Then release the buttons and then press and hold them again.
> 5. Keep pressing the buttons until the recovery mode menu will be displayed on your LG G2.
> 6. That’s it.
> 7. If you then want to go back to Android OS, just select “reboot system now”.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work for me. Is it because I am still using the stock ROM and am unrooted?